# java - How to resolve a InputMismatchException caused by a data file with mixed data types

Tags: java, input, io

My program reads in data from a file that contains integers and real numbers and assigns the numbers into 2 different arrays. It reads in everything fine until I add a characters to the data file that are supposed to act as menu options. Here is an example.

```
127856 55.55
569334 100.50
987104 2.33
222382 5000.00
321333 999.99
q
```

q refers to a menu option that pretty much ends the program.

```
char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
switch (choice) {
case 'q':
case 'Q':
printAccts(acctNum, balance, numaccts);
notDone = false;
break;
```

The q at the end of the data file causes the error. The compiler tells me that the IntputMismatchException happens at two lines. Here, where acctnum and balance are the arrays and max is just a constant integer.

```
int numaccts = readAccts(acctNum, balance, MAX);
```

And at the line that is between ** **.

```
public static int readAccts(int[] acctNum, double[] balance, int maxAccts)
throws Exception {
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("bankdata.txt"));
int count = 0;

while (sc2.hasNext() && count < maxAccts) {
**acctNum[count] = sc2.nextInt();**
balance[count] = sc2.nextDouble();
count++;
}
```

I don't think I have ever encountered this problem before and I don't know what techniques I could use to fix it. Any ideas?

*EDIT* the first block of code and second block of code are in different methods

Comment: Use the `hasNextInt()` and `hasNextDouble()` methods to ensure that there is indeed an `int/double`?

Comment: @GBlodgett Thanks for responding. Could you get into a little more detail on what you mean by that? Do you mean using hasnextInt() and hasNextDouble() in an if state or for my while loop?

Comment: Well for context here what is `q`? Why is it at the end of your file?

Comment: @GBlodgett Sorry about that. q in the program refers to a case in a switch that is supposed to quit the program. so once it hits q it should call to a method and then stop. I'll edit in some of the code into my question.

Comment: @GBlodgett made the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is implement the `hasNextInt()` and `hasNextDouble()` methods:

```
while (sc2.hasNext() && count < maxAccts) {  
  if(!sc2.hasNextInt() || !sc2.hasNextDouble()) {
            break;
  }
  acctNum[count] = sc2.nextInt();
  balance[count] = sc2.nextDouble();

}
```

Comment: I think you believe that the switch code and he while code are part of the same method. My fault for leaving that out.  I'll edit it in.

Comment: your code works. It doesn't work if i add the character to the line below a a pair of numbers, but it works if i add the character next to it like this. 321333 999.9 q

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Comment: @H.i It doesn't? When I run this with it on it's own line it still works

Comment: nevermind it works if q is in its own line. I must've fudged something up. I have another problem that arose. should I just ask it here or make a new question?

Comment: @H.i You should ask it in a new question.

Comment: I just posted the question right now. Tried fixing it for about an hour but some other problems popped up. Thanks for your help earlier